# IP for SAP (Sender Authentication Package)

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

Due to very low volume of emails, we have decided to go with shared IPs for SAP in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. We have dedicated subdomains and dedicated email address just the IPs will be shared. Please help with the following questions.

1. Can we go with any shared IP within the organization (outside the subdomain) or there are any issues/restrictions?
2. Can we configure the shared IP with dedicated subdomains and dedicated email address combination?
3. Later if the email volume goes up, will there be any additional cost in updating SAP with dedicated IP
4. Does Salesforce offers shared IP’s to be used for our setup (dedicated subdomain/dedicated email)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the concept of a sender IP. It is not one of your IPs, and you have no control over which specific IP address is assigned to you. Salesforce will provide you with the IP, regardless if you decide on a private or shared IP. This decision is part of the SAP form you will be submitting, asking Salesforce to configure your account:

[image]

Hence:

1. No, you will get a shared IP provided by Salesforce. It will also not be a fixed IP, as you will be placed on an IP pool, and reallocated based on volume, reputation etc.
2. Yes. There is no difference in how a Sender Authentication Package is applied, whether you go with a Private or a Shared IP.
3. There will be a need for purchasing a dedicated IP SKU, as you can't "save the private IP for later", which is part of your SAP. If you initially configure it with a shared IP, the private IP is "lost".
4. Yes, as I wrote in the beginning, it will be Salesforce that provides the IPs for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Regarding #1 - This is making sense but online I read that SAP should be configured with dedicated IP. If Salesforce makes the decision on shared/private IPs, how can organizations opt for private IP?

#2 - Again, if Salesforce makes IP decision, how can we go with shared or private IP?

#3 - Can you please elaborate this. Is this correct understanding that by default Salesforce will assign shared IP and we can purchase dedicated IP later if email volume goes up?

Comment: @AT_SFMC - When you fill out your SAP form, where you provide details about your domain, you should let Salesforce know, that you require a shared IP. They will configure your account accordingly. The default decision, unless notified differently is AFAIK configuring the SAP with a dedicated IP. But again: provide your preference when filling out the SAP form.

Comment: @AT_SFMC - I think I know why you have misinterpreted my answer. I have updated it, to be more precise.

Comment: @AT_SFMC - I have also added the dropdown from SAP request form, where you get to choose the type of IP you need. Also, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful.

Comment: @Lucas,Thank-you!